# static/generic/non-generic definitions error

Tags: c#

Techies--
I think I'm defining this static extension correctly for Split, I obviously am not because the message: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class.

This is a simple c# console program to test something. Here's what I have:

```
class Program
{ 
  static int Main(string[] args)
  {
    int[] numbers = new int[10000]; 
           for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i) 
               numbers[i] = i; 

  int[][] sectionedNumbers = numbers.Split(1000); 
   .
   . //blah blah blah .. rest of code

 return 0;
 }

 public static T[][] Split<T>(this T[] arrayIn, int length)
 {
  bool even = arrayIn.Length % length == 0;
    .
    .
    . // blah blah .. more code

   return newArray;
   }
```

What is it that I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello your container class must be static

Set you method in static class

```
public static class Extension
{
 public static T[][] Split<T>(this T[] arrayIn, int length)
 {
  bool even = arrayIn.Length % length == 0;
    .
    .
    . // blah blah .. more code

   return newArray;
   }

}
```

Comment: There's a `class` keyword missing in your class declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Program` is not static as requested by the error message.

- Add the `static` directive to the class declaration:

  ```
   static class Program
   {
       // ...
  ```
- or move `Split` into another static class altogether.

Then your code should compile again.

Comment: O.R. Mapper -- thanks so much, i forgot to even look at the program def... i was waayyy to focused on the the extension code. I'm all patched up!:-)

Comment: @plditallo: Could you please accept this or one of the other equivalent answers if your problem has been solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your extension method in a class, like this:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
 public static T[][] Split<T>(this T[] arrayIn, int length) 
 { 
  bool even = arrayIn.Length % length == 0; 
    . 
    . 
    . // blah blah .. more code 

   return newArray; 
   } 
}
```